# Publishing Image Services in ArcGIS Server vs. Tile Cache Data Store

Tags: arcgis-server, imagery

Historically I've published images services through ArcGIS Server, but I now have an ArcGIS Enterprise tile cache data store on a dedicated server and I'm considering moving some image services over to it. I have successfully published a large image service to the tile cache data store and it works great. Our image services are basic cached image services which do not use any mosaic dataset functions, and they are static image sets that do not change. Moving image services to would relieve some of the pressure on ArcGIS Server. So, my questions are these:

1. Is there a performance difference between ArcGIS Server image services and the tile cache data store?
2. Are there any negatives to moving image services to the data store?

Comment: I think the tile cache data store is for 3D data for hosted scene layers, not traditional map services. https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/data-store/10.7/install/windows/what-is-arcgis-data-store.htm